# With an IoC container, should a constructor still check if a parameter is null?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ioc-container

I was looking through the Orchard CMS Project source code and I noticed that some of their constructors never verify that the required parameter is not null. At first, I thought this was odd. I asked my self, "Considering that you're saying this dependency is required, wouldn't you want to check that you actually have one?" Realizing that the project uses Castle Windsor as an IoC container, I later then thought, "Well, the container would have thrown the exception when it tried to find the dependency for the object that had the requirement." So my question stands, should I still check when I know that an IoC container will check for me?

Or is the double check good because I'm, in a sense, adhering to a reverse encapsulation principle stating: "I don't know how I'm getting this dependency, but I really need one!"

Comment: Here's an interesting article by Mark Seemann about this subject: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/07/08/defensive-coding/

Comment: Thanks for that.... I've been becoming quiet the fan of Mark. I've always said that you should check the requirements of the method before processing on because it makes the troubleshooting easier when you run into a problem.

Comment: To be honest, nowadays I don't check constructor arguments anymore for classes that are wired by the container. I know my container (and most containers) will never allow injecting null into the constructor. So leaving out the checks in that case is safe and makes the code more readable, more maintainable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been led to follow the practice of checking every visible parameter for NULL regardless of how it's been designed to be instantiated. There's always a chance that someone will choose a different IoC container that enforces a more loose type delegation policy or some junior developer finds your code and hopes it'll work the way they want.

Either way, better safe than sorry. In this case better spend a couple seconds guarding the code then hours when someone decides to use it as unintended.

Comment: That's the way I've always thought as well. But This situation made me realize that In all my production code I have never had  a ArgumentNullException in a constructor be thrown because of the IoC container. Just seemed like extra noise in my code.

Answer (score 4):

I would not check. I think it's going to unnecessarily clutter your constructors.

If your DI container does not have the required dependency, your testing, manual or automatic should catch this very quickly.

By having something as a parameter to a constructor you are saying that it is *required*.

Also, what do you do if you somehow get a null parameter?

Does the constructor attempt to construct a new of the null type? Probably not because this constructor should have no idea what the passed in type needs to instantiate itself.

At this point you should just catch the exception and gracefully exit or move on; but you should have code for this situation anyway.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate... Wouldn't the ArgumentNullException be more telling vs. a NullReferenceException when troubleshooting the problem?

Comment: As with much in programming, I think we are in the realm of preference.

Comment: The smaller methods get the less it is to get a `NullReferenceException`, because the easier it is to spot which reference is null :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Class design must be agnostic of how its dependencies are injected and must always protect its invariants.

Answer (score 3):

Latest versions of Ninject and Structure map will both throw an binding exception before you enter the constructor. 
So having a check for argument null exception in the constructor will not help anyway.

So I vote for keeping your code clean.

I'm not saying defensive code doesn't have a place but constructor checks isn't one if you are using modern IoC.

While there's always a chance that someone in the future will choose a different IoC container that doesn't enforces a strict type delegation policy. I feel is a "what if" argument, changing IoC is a pretty big architecture decisions and personally the cost of auto generating null checks probably wouldn't weigh to much into it.

To me the likely hood of someone coming in and needing to read your code is way higher. Easier to read code is usually less likely to be buggy and is also quicker to maintain.